# How can I split a where with OR's onto more lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeresource

I am trying to implement a search function searching through all the fields in a model to find matching records.

**I would like to split my `where` query at the `OR`'s onto different lines. How can I do this?**

This is a working example:

```
u = User.where("LOWER(id) LIKE ? OR LOWER(name) LIKE ?", s, s)
```

But I want to implement a lot more fields so to make things more readable, I would like to split the where's to different lines e.g.:

```
u = User.where("LOWER(id) LIKE ?", s)
u << User.where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", s)
u << User.where("LOWER(surname) LIKE ?", s)
```

This works but may return duplicate records for instance if a name and surname is the same etc. I could run this and then remove all duplicates, but the data-set is too big to iterate over it afterwards. I also need this in an `ActiveRecord::Relation` to perform other commands on it.

Is there a way to do this, or should I just keep it all on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your point is readability, I'd suggest to take 2 variables -

> ```
> query_statement = "LOWER(id) LIKE ? OR " + 
>                   "LOWER(name) LIKE ? "
>
>
> query_variables = s,s
> ```

and then use these two variables in the actual query :

> u = User.where("#{query_statement}, #{query_variables}")

Hope this helps !!

If you find some better option, Do post here! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this also.

```
with_names = User.where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", s)
with_surnames = User.where("LOWER(surname) LIKE ?", s)
@result = with_names | with_surnames
```